# LINQ to XML query from multiple ListBox items

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I need an example of linq to xml query.

I have two ListBoxes with `SelectionMode` set to `Multiple`.

My query for populating first ListBox is:

```
var query = doc.Root.Descendants("Articles")
                    .OrderBy(b => b.Element("Category").Value)
                    .Select(b => b.Element("Category").Value)
                    .Distinct();
```

and binding it with:

```
lbxItems.DataSource = query;
lbxItems.DataBind();
```

So i have all the values in first ListBox, and when i select item from that ListBox i want to populate second ListBox.

So on `SelectedIndexChanged` i have another query:

```
var query = doc.Root.Descendants("Articles")
                .Where(b => b.Element("Category").Value.Equals(lbxItems.SelectedValue))
                    .OrderBy(b => b.Element("SubCategory").Value)
                    .Select(b => b.Element("SubCategory").Value)
                    .Distinct();
```

That's working if i select one item, but i need a query that is doing the same thing but from multiple selected items.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your where clause like so:

```
.Where(b => lbxItems.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>() // needs a cast
    .Where(i => i.Selected)
    .Select(i => i.Value)
    .Contains(b.Element("Category").Value))
```

The idea is to determine what items are selected and see if your category value is among those selected.

Comment: Thank you for this but this is throwing an error:
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

I'am really starting learning so i don't know where to go from here.
Thanks

Comment: @ereyes: Ah, the `Items` property returns a `ListItemCollection` which can't perform LINQ operations.  It should work now.